# DexGuard - Encryptclasses NullPointerException with Robolectric

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, robolectric, dexguard

I am having problems running DexGuard with -encryptclasses for some classes. The problem only happens when running a Robolectric unit test. I get a NullPointerException from any class that was obfuscated and encrypted by DexGuard. If I turn off the encryptclasses flag it works in Robolectric.

The configuration also works for devices and emulators: running the application in an Android environment (tested in Dalvik and ART devices and emulators) work just fine. Android Instrumentation tests also works. Only when running through Robolectric I get a NullPointerException. If I disable DexGuard encryptclasses everything works in Robolectric too.

DexGuard is being used in a library that I depend upon. This library is added in libs folder of my gradle module.

I would post this as a Robolectric issue but they probably can't reproduce without a license of the DexGuard tool.

Setup is:

- Android Studio 1.3.2
- Android Gradle Plugin 1.3.1
- Android build tools version 23.0.0
- Android compileSdkVersion 22
- Oracle JDK 8
- Ubuntu 15.04 64 bits
- DexGuard version: 5.5.00

Answer (score 1):

Robolectric uses Reflection quite intensively and any kind of obfuscation are really easy breaking this functionality.

I would create build configuration for testing purposes where I would switch off dexguarding. Same as debug by default which is not obfuscating your code by default.

The matter of your unit test is to test small piece of functionality and not to test combination of build process with obfuscation and your code functionality.

I would also write to DexGuard people checking if dexguard is doing obfuscation at the correct place. My understanding that running Robolectric test on VM should not be yet any kind obfuscated

Comment: I agree with you and that is actually what I do in most cases. The issue here is that a lib I depend upon is dexguarded. I do not have the source code for that nor do I have control of how it is built. So I can't go this route here.

Comment: What class do you use form library? Can you wrap it in your class and mock it?

Comment: I need PowerMock or other to mock static final methods. I have circumvented its usage through DIs but I would really like to be able to test the whole integration as a Robolectric test. I still am curious as to why it works in Dalvik/ART and not with JVM.